# Angularjs request encoding issue

Tags: angularjs, http, content-type

As part of the service response there is some content received in local language. The response from the server looks fine, but the moment it's received through
angular.js $http, the content in local language is distorted.

I've tried both the methods given below, but no luck. Can someone help please?

Method 1:

```
appService.config(function($httpProvider) { 
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8' };
});
$http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);

    });
```

Method 2:

```
$http.get(url,{ transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}}
     ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);

    });
```

Angular response content looks something like this �����

Comment: what lang is the reponse data in ?

Comment: The response data contains some Hindi laguage content

Comment: maybe it doesnt recognize the font .so download the font and add it to view where its being  displayed

Comment: Already added the font to the browser where I'm viewing the content. When I view the service response directly through browser, the content looks ok. If I directly hardcode the content in angular scope, and view it in the HTML it looks ok. The problem is with the content received through $http

Comment: Try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce             $sce.trustAsHtml("the data recieved")